# Getting rid of unwanted double quotes

Tags: php, json

```
echo '<tr class="questiontd"><td>'.htmlspecialchars($question).'</td>';
echo "<td class='addtd'><button type='button' class='add' onclick=\"parent.addwindow('$question');\">Add</button></td></tr>";
```

Now to above code will display this for example:

> Question           Button
>
> "What is 2+2"      Add(button)

But I do not want `""` around the question, I want it to be displayed like below:

> Question           Button
>
> What is 2+2        Add(button)

Does anyone know how I can remove the double quotes around the text? (if you need more code then please comment to me)

Comment: show the code, where `$question` gets set.

Comment: Why are you json encoding the question when you are just spitting out html? Don't encode it and you probably won't get the quotes.

Answer (score 4):

You are inserting text into HTML. To escape it use `htmlspecialchars`. HTML is not JSON. Do not use `json_encode`.

```
echo '<tr class="questiontd"><td>'.htmlspecialchars($question).'</td>';
```

Comment: I have changed my code to htmlspecialchars, I updated the code in my question to include htmlspecialchars, the only problem those is that lets say I type this in for my question `!"�$%^&*()-='.,:;/?#~*/\\><` (this is simply a test for all characters) and then I click on the "Add" button then I receive an error stating: `unterminated string literal: parent.addwindow('!/` How can I remove this error?

Answer (score 0):

Remove json_encode from the second line. If you json-encode a string it will always be in double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to remove them.

```
echo '<tr class="questiontd"><td>', htmlspecialchars($question), '</td>';
```

The translations performed are:

```
'&' (ampersand) becomes '&amp;'
'"' (double quote) becomes '&quot;' when ENT_NOQUOTES is not set.
"'" (single quote) becomes '&#039;' (or &apos;) only when ENT_QUOTES is set.
'<' (less than) becomes '&lt;'
'>' (greater than) becomes '&gt;'
```

Comment: I have changed my code to htmlspecialchars, I updated the code in my question to include htmlspecialchars, the only problem those is that lets say I type this in for my question `!"�$%^&*()-='.,:;/?#~*/\\><` (this is simply a test for all characters) and then I click on the "Add" button then I receive an error stating: `unterminated string literal: parent.addwindow('!/` How can I remove this error?

Answer (score 0):

This is true

> Why are you json encoding the question when you are just spitting out html? Don't encode it and you probably won't get the quotes.

But for a simple solution if you still insist in using json_encode

```
echo '<tr class="questiontd"><td>'.str_replace(json_encode($question),"\"","").'</td>';
```

or more elegantly

```
echo '<tr class="questiontd"><td>'.htmlspecialchars($question).'</td>';
```

Comment: I have changed my code to htmlspecialchars, I updated the code in my question to include htmlspecialchars, the only problem those is that lets say I type this in for my question `!"�$%^&*()-='.,:;/?#~*/\\><` (this is simply a test for all characters) and then I click on the "Add" button then I receive an error stating: `unterminated string literal: parent.addwindow('!/` How can I remove this error?

Comment: Did you miss a `'` or `"`? And yeah, there I see, you had given a `"`

Comment: I can't see where there is a missed ' or "